# TinyMCE - Image size attributes issue IE10 - Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

I am using SnailCMS with TinyMCE 4. When TinyMCE resizes an image it adds the size as attributes and not inline styles. Since IE10 ignores the width & height attributes the images do not resize and stay the original size!

I know this is not a new issue but I have been searching and searching for a resolution but I cannot find one anywhere!

Has anyone resolved this?

Also: commenting out img{-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;} did not work for me.

Thanks all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I properly understand what you're asking. What I believe you're asking is that when you add an image to the text field that TinyMCE overrides, the image that is displayed is smaller than the actual file that you chose through the image selection widget. What I always do when I used TinyMCE is stick in the classic meta elements in the head of my page, which consist of:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Website</title>
  <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="(your desc. here...)">
  <meta name="author" content="(your name here...)">
</meta>
```

If you notice the 4th line, that forces IE's rendering engine to ALWAYS be the latest version. Because TinyMCE isn't know for being to "up-to-date" at times and having IE issues, this will make sure that images rendered through IE always appear in the latest dimensions, as that is what the latest version of IE's rendering engine (as of this post) does.

I eventually discovered [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/), which is a MUCH better option for an efficient, up-to-date, open-source, and widely compatible text editor. I would highly recommend looking into it.

Hope this helps!